# Copy and reverse char* in the C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, pointers, char

I would like to copy reversed `char*` to the another `char*`. I miss one letter in the second line of the output.

I did:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void cp(char *str2, char *str1){
    char *pom1 = str1;
    while(*pom1){
        pom1++;
    }
    char* pom2 = str2;
    while(*pom1 != *str1){
         pom1--;
        *pom2 = *pom1;
         pom2++;
    }
    *pom2 = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "ppC", str2[10] = "Witaj";
    cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << endl;
    cp(str2,str1);
    cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << endl;
    cp(str2,"CJP");
    cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Napis str2 Witaj
Napis str2 Cp
Napis str2 PJC
```

While it should be:

```
Napis str2 Witaj
Napis str2 Cpp
Napis str2 PJC
```

Comment: You're missing a couple `const`s: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e33543fd7143a56

Comment: No, you're missing a couple of `std::string`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is in this statement of the function

```
while(*pom1 != *str1){
```

There must be

```
while( pom1 != str1){
```

Take into account that string literals have type of constant arrays. So for example variable str1 has to be declared as

```
const char *str1 = "ppC";
```

Also the function should be declared as

```
void cp( char *str2, const char *str1 );
```

Also It will be useful to know that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`:)

Comment: @riv You are wrong. String literals in C++ have types of constant arrays.

Comment: `char* a = "aa";` compiles just fine.

Comment: @riv It is totally unimportant whether a compiler compiles this statement. It does not influense on the type of string literals according to the C++ Standard.

Comment: Okay so be it, but you used their constness as an argument to why "str1 has to be declared as const", when every compiler will let it by (and doing otherwise would break backward compatibility).

Comment: @riv not every compiler will let it by, obviously!

Comment: Well mine did (VS2010) :3 This is somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075049/why-do-compilers-allow-string-literals-not-to-be-const   Also `VirtualProtect` allows bypassing the constness if you need it for some wicked reason, so its mostly a  limitation imposed by the OS.

Comment: @riv str1 must have qualifier const because it is its type according to the standard. . There is no any "backward compatibility".

Comment: Actually `char* a = "aa";` will compiler with warnings at certain warning lavel. Make it `const` if you want to silence it.

Comment: @TheMask: Depends on the compiler. It will not compile by Standard. And it should not compile.

Comment: @TheMask: In C++03, yes, because it was deprecated. However, in C++11, the conversion was entirely removed and your compiler should produce an _error_, then refuse to build. Yes, this _does_ break backward compatibility with earlier C++ versions, and that's why it was deprecated first.

Comment: /cc @riv Truth above ^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But about `const` will still works in C++11 or it's should produce error too?

Comment: @TheMask: I'm sorry? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: My bad. I mean, Will `const char *a = "a";` produce an error in C++11?

Comment: so far I know, there's a difference from `char *a = "a";` because in the previously example compiler (such as clang) didn't produce warning

Comment: @TheMask: No, because `const char* a = "a";` is the _correct_ way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

> There's `reverse_copy` in the stdlib

... and that it's used like:

```
template <typename CharT, size_t Ndest>
void cp(CharT (&dest)[Ndest], CharT const *src){
    auto f = src, l = src + std::strlen(src);
    assert(std::distance(f,l) < Ndest);
    *(std::reverse_copy(f, l, dest)) = '\0';
}
```

So, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/866758952101c060)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

template <typename CharT, size_t Ndest>
void cp(CharT (&dest)[Ndest], CharT const *src){
    auto f = src, l = src + std::strlen(src);
    assert(std::distance(f,l) < Ndest);
    *(std::reverse_copy(f, l, dest)) = '\0';
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char str1[]   = "ppC";
    char str2[10] = "Witaj";

    std::cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << std::endl;
    cp(str2, str1);
    std::cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << std::endl;
    cp(str2,"CJP");
    std::cout << "Napis str2 "<< str2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Standard Library, `std::reverse_copy()` in this case:

```
std::reverse_copy( input , input + strlen( input ) , output );
```

Answer (score 0):

copy paste solution

```
int len(const char *p) {
    int c = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        c++;
        p++;
    }
    return(c);
}

void cp(char *str2, const char *str1){
if(!(len(str2)<len(str1))){
   const char *pom1 = str1;

    while(*pom1){
        pom1++;
    }
    char* pom2 = str2;
   while( pom1 != str1){
         pom1--;
        *pom2 = *pom1;
         pom2++;
    }
    *pom2 = '\0';
}
}
```