# Passing non-const arguments to const function parameters in C

Tags: c, gcc, constants

I have a function that specifies a const parameter to indicate to the caller that it won't be modfied:

```
int func1(const char *some_string) 
{
    // Do something non-destructive with some_string
}
```

I pass a non-const variable as an argument to `func1`:

```
int func2(void)
{
    char *my_string = "my text";
    func1(my_string);
}
```

gcc reports:

```
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

What is the correct way to deal with this situation? Creating a const copy of `my_string` seems a bit much, but simply casting seems like burying the warning.

Comment: It's not warning about the function call, it's warning about the initialisation of my_string. If you had const char *my_string = "my_test"; it wouldn't complain...

Comment: The problem cannot get reproduced with the code posted - the code is perfectly fine. I would suspect that you are accidentally compiling the code as C++.

Comment: @Joe That's not correct. String literals are of type `char[]` in C, unlike C++.

Comment: @Lundin, it's an inherited project using autotools. How can I determine if it was compiled for C++?

Comment: @retrodev `#ifdef __cplusplus #error something #endif`` and your program won't compile any more if C++...

Comment: If you don't even know which compiler you are using, this warning is the least of your problems... I don't know anything about autotools, sorry.

Comment: What happens when you replace char *my_string with char my_string[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having stems from your `main` function.

When you declare `char *my_string = "my text";`,you are creating a non-const pointer to a string literal. By design, string literals such as `"my text"` are immutable, and therefore const in the language. (In practice, the compilers usually put the string literals into a specific section of the executable which contains read-only memory, so attempting to modify the literal using the non-const pointer can lead to a segfault.)

By declaring a non-const pointer to the string literal, you end up with a pointer which you *could* use to modify the immutable string literal, which is considered undefined behavior in C.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault) for more information.

The easiest way to solve this is to simply change `char *my_string` into `const char *my_string`.

Comment: This does not explain the warning. Even though string literals are guaranteed to be stored in read-only memory, their type is still a read/write one `char[]`. This is a well-known defect in the language, that was fixed in C++ but not in C.

Comment: Good point! It seems that the reasoning behind the non-constness of string literals in C is a little fuzzy. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075049/why-do-compilers-allow-string-literals-not-to-be-const)

Comment: Historical reasons. Some old crap systems (DOS for example) did allow you to write to string literals and many crappy programmers abused that. To be backwards-compatible with crap programs for crap systems, C kept the string literal type as `char[]`. While C++ soundly recognized all such arguments as nonsense and changed string literals to the correct type `const char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `const char *my_string = "my text";` instead of `char *my_string = "my text";`

Comment: This does not explain the warning, assuming the code is compiled as C.

Comment: @Lundin If use gcc, it will no warning. But if use g++, it will warning.

Comment: Yes, because they are different languages. But this was tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because the project is compiled with `-Wwrite-strings` *extra* warning. This warning is not enabled by default by any common warning options, `-Wall`, `-Wextra` because it can make even *strictly conforming* C programs produce diagnostics messages.

Namely

```
char *foo = "bar";
```

is a strictly conforming C fragment as such, `"bar"` being a non-modifiable array of type `char [4]`. Using `char *` for the type is not the best practice though, and `const char *foo` should use instead if possible. The `-Wwrite-strings` makes this not-the-best practice *visible*. It is just meant as an aide to write better programs but it as such doesn't uncover the real problems.